# Class 'TableViewController' has no initializers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applescript, tableview

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var titleArray = [String]()
    var idArray = [UUID()]
    var chosenTitle = ""
    var chosenTitleID : UUID
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.add, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonClicked))
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        getData()
    }
    
    func getData() {
        
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Places")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
        do {
            let results = try context.fetch(request)
            
            if results.count > 0 {
                
                self.titleArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.idArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                
                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                    
                    if let title = result.value(forKey: "title") as? String {
                        self.titleArray.append(title)
                        
                    }
                    if let id = result.value(forKey: "id") as? UUID {
                        self.idArray.append(id)
                    }
                    
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell  = UITableViewCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return titleArray.count
        }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        chosenTitle = titleArray[indexPath.row]
        chosenTitleID = idArray[indexPath.row]
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailsVC", sender: nil)
    }
```

I have a problem with Swift class. I have a swift file for UITableViewController class. I had "Class 'TableViewController' has no initializers" problem.
I didn't find anything but the code says TableViewController has no initializers. I don't understand this problem. I have version 14.2.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Your class contains non-optional properties with no default values (`chosenTitleID`). You need to either create an initializer which sets those properties, or given them default values.

Comment: ...or make them optional.

Comment: And you got a typo `var idArray = [UUID()]` should read `var idArray = [UUID]()`

Answer (score 1):

You can make **chosenTitleID** property optional(var chosenTitleID: UUID?) or provide the default value to **chosenTitleID** because TableViewController class contains non-optional property.